# How does android manage its application users?

Tags: android, linux

If I recall correctly, whenever an new app is installed on the android device, a unix user and group correspond to the app will be created. So whenever the app writes to its own /data/data/(app identifier) folder, those file written will be owned by that specific app user.

However, when I try to look for those app users in /system/etc/passwd (if I remember correctly), they don't exist there. So I am wondering how does Android manage those app users?

Comment: does your device is rooted in which you are finding/checking files?

Comment: if i remember correctly those directories are not available for users and u must root your device first. ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144375/does-the-android-operating-system-have-files-like-etc-passwd-etc-shadow-and